# Mapping nested object to table html to create tree by parent and child data

Tags: javascript, html, object, recursion, tree

I have a case to mapping nested object to table html to create tree by parent and child data. But the current result the parents still repeated and the data tree still not fulfilled the expected result.

Current result:

```
ID  Name
1   A.1
1.1 A.1.1
1.1.1   A.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 A.1.1.1.1
1   A.1
1.1 A.1.1
1.1.2   A.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 A.1.1.1.1
1   A.1
1.1 A.1.1
1.1.1   A.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 A.1.1.1.1
1   A.1
1.1 A.1.1
1.1.1   A.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 A.1.1.1.1
1   B.1
1.1 B.1.1
1.1.1   B.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 A.1.1.1.1
1   B.1
1.1 B.1.1
1.1.2   B.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 A.1.1.1.1
1   B.1
1.1 B.1.1
1.1.1   B.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 A.1.1.1.1
1   B.1
1.1 B.1.1
1.1.1   B.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 A.1.1.1.1
```

Expected result on table:

```
| ID | Name |
=============
| "1" | "A.1" |
| "1.1" | "A.1.1" |
| "1.1.1" | "A.1.1.1" |
| "1.1.2" | "A.1.1.2" |
| "1.1.1.1" | "A.1.1.1.1" |
| "1.1.1.1" | "A.1.1.1.2" |
| "2" | "B.1" |
| "1.1" | "B.1.1" |
| "1.1.1" | "B.1.1.1" |
| "1.1.2" | "B.1.1.2" |
| "1.1.1.1" | "B.1.1.1.1" |
| "1.1.1.1" | "B.1.1.1.2" |
```

My full code can be found on https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-shadow-twdlbo?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";

const datas = {
  A: {
    id: "1",
    name: "A.1",
    child: {
      A1: {
        id: "1.1",
        name: "A.1.1",
        child: {
          A11: {
            id: "1.1.1",
            name: "A.1.1.1",
            child: {
              A111: {
                id: "1.1.1.1",
                name: "A.1.1.1.1"
              }
            }
          },
          A12: {
            id: "1.1.2",
            name: "A.1.1.1",
            child: {
              A111: {
                id: "1.1.1.1",
                name: "A.1.1.1.1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      A2: {
        id: "1.1",
        name: "A.1.1",
        child: {
          A11: {
            id: "1.1.1",
            name: "A.1.1.1",
            child: {
              A111: {
                id: "1.1.1.1",
                name: "A.1.1.1.1"
              }
            }
          },
          A12: {
            id: "1.1.1",
            name: "A.1.1.1",
            child: {
              A111: {
                id: "1.1.1.1",
                name: "A.1.1.1.1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  B: {
    id: "1",
    name: "B.1",
    child: {
      B1: {
        id: "1.1",
        name: "B.1.1",
        child: {
          B11: {
            id: "1.1.1",
            name: "B.1.1.1",
            child: {
              A111: {
                id: "1.1.1.1",
                name: "A.1.1.1.1"
              }
            }
          },
          B12: {
            id: "1.1.2",
            name: "B.1.1.1",
            child: {
              A111: {
                id: "1.1.1.1",
                name: "A.1.1.1.1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      B2: {
        id: "1.1",
        name: "B.1.1",
        child: {
          B11: {
            id: "1.1.1",
            name: "B.1.1.1",
            child: {
              A111: {
                id: "1.1.1.1",
                name: "A.1.1.1.1"
              }
            }
          },
          B12: {
            id: "1.1.1",
            name: "B.1.1.1",
            child: {
              A111: {
                id: "1.1.1.1",
                name: "A.1.1.1.1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

export default function App() {
  const renderRows = (parentData, dataArr = []) => {
    const newDataArr = [
      ...dataArr,
      <tr>
        <td>{parentData.id}</td>
        <td>{parentData.name}</td>
      </tr>
    ];

    if (!parentData.child) return newDataArr;
    return Object.values(parentData.child).map((child) =>
      renderRows(child, newDataArr)
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{Object.values(datas).map((data) => renderRows(data))}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In the "expected table" section you use a format that does not resemble a table. Can you format it as a table? It is not clear whether your table has 2 columns or more, and how the indentation of text translates to a column...

Comment: @trincot I have update the expected table

Comment: I don't really understand your input structure. There are duplicate nodes, like `A111`, which have different parents. I don't understand how you decide which of these different parents you want to be the "true" parent in the output.

Comment: And I don't understand your output structure.  You seem to want a combination of breadth-first ordering (`1.1.1` and `1.1.2` before `1.1.1.1`) and depth-first ordering (all of `1` s descendants before any of `2`s,)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, your output structure seems confused. To flatten out your tree into an array of nodes is a fairly simple recursion.  To then turn this array into a display table string is also simple.  But any way to do this would involve a more consistent ordering, either depth-first or breadth-first.

Here's one depth-first approach:

```js
const flatten = (o) => Object .values (o) 
  .flatMap (({child = {}, ...rest}) => [rest, ...flatten (child)])

const toTable = (xs) => 
  `| ID | Name |\n=============\n` + 
  xs .map (({id, name}) => `| ${id} | ${name} |`) .join ('\n')

const nestedToTable = (o) => toTable (flatten (o))


const datas = {A: {id: "1", name: "A.1", child: {A1: {id: "1.1", name: "A.1.1", child: {A11: {id: "1.1.1", name: "A.1.1.1", child: {A111: {id: "1.1.1.1", name: "A.1.1.1.1"}}}, A12: {id: "1.1.2", name: "A.1.1.1", child: {A111: {id: "1.1.1.1", name: "A.1.1.1.1"}}}}}, A2: {id: "1.1", name: "A.1.1", child: {A11: {id: "1.1.1", name: "A.1.1.1", child: {A111: {id: "1.1.1.1", name: "A.1.1.1.1"}}}, A12: {id: "1.1.1", name: "A.1.1.1", child: {A111: {id: "1.1.1.1", name: "A.1.1.1.1"}}}}}}}, B: {id: "1", name: "B.1", child: {B1: {id: "1.1", name: "B.1.1", child: {B11: {id: "1.1.1", name: "B.1.1.1", child: {A111: {id: "1.1.1.1", name: "A.1.1.1.1"}}}, B12: {id: "1.1.2", name: "B.1.1.1", child: {A111: {id: "1.1.1.1", name: "A.1.1.1.1"}}}}}, B2: {id: "1.1", name: "B.1.1", child: {B11: {id: "1.1.1", name: "B.1.1.1", child: {A111: {id: "1.1.1.1", name: "A.1.1.1.1"}}}, B12: {id: "1.1.1", name: "B.1.1.1", child: {A111: {id: "1.1.1.1", name: "A.1.1.1.1"}}}}}}}}

console .log (nestedToTable (datas))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

But this seems to have more output data than your request, and it's ordered differently.  So can you explain the logic of your output as it relates to the input?